# Isotope filter with jquery css overlays not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope, masonry

I have a strange problem, I am using isotope's filterable function to sort through elements in my portfolio. When the user hovers over some portfolio element an overlay is triggered using the following code:

```
/***************************************************
        PORTFOLIO ITEM IMAGE HOVER
***************************************************/
$(window).load(function(){

    $(".portfolio-grid ul li .item-info-overlay").hide();

    if( is_touch_device() ){
        $(".portfolio-grid ul li").click(function(){

            var count_before = $(this).closest("li").prevAll("li").length;

            var this_opacity = $(this).find(".item-info-overlay").css("opacity");
            var this_display = $(this).find(".item-info-overlay").css("display");


            if ((this_opacity == 0) || (this_display == "none")) {
                $(this).find(".item-info-overlay").fadeTo(250, 1);
            } else {
                $(this).find(".item-info-overlay").fadeTo(250, 0);
            }

            $(this).closest("ul").find("li:lt(" + count_before + ") .item-info-overlay").fadeTo(250, 0);
            $(this).closest("ul").find("li:gt(" + count_before + ") .item-info-overlay").fadeTo(250, 0);    

        }); 

    }
    else{   
            $(".portfolio-grid ul li").hover(function(){
                $(this).find(".item-info-overlay").fadeTo(250, 1);
                }, function() {
                    $(this).find(".item-info-overlay").fadeTo(250, 0);      
            });

        }
});
```

However, sometimes other elements that are hidden due to the way isotope filters receive the 'overlay' property/class (confirmed in Chrome inspector) when the ones that are shown do not. I think it has something to do with the `$(this).find` selecting the wrong elements as it doesn't understand the filter from isotope, but I can't be sure.

The phenomenon is visible if you go to http://fagardesigns.com/portfolio click 'aftermovie' and scroll over the 'Paint Splash' 2nd row 3rd to the right.

If you reload the page, this sometimes disappears which is also the strange thing.

Comment: Instead of your Personal/Project site link you can create a DEMO. Using online tools (plunker/jsfiddle/codepen).

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I see: It works if you choose ALL as the filter then switch to the other filters. However, in your **jquery.isotope.min.js** where your initializing the isotope (*why are you doing it here instead of in your custom.js?*), your initial filter is `advertisement`

```
var $container = $('#thumbs');
      $container.isotope({
        filter: '.advertisement', <= why is this the initial filter?
        itemSelector : '.item',
        animationEngine : 'jquery',
        animationOptions: {
            duration: 250,
            easing: 'linear',
            queue: false
        }
      });
```

And why are you re-initializing the isotope when the Window resizes?

```
    $(window).resize(function() {
        var $container = $('#thumbs');
            $container.isotope({
                filter: '.advertisement',
                itemSelector : '.item',
                animationEngine : 'jquery',
                animationOptions: {
                    duration: 250,
                    easing: 'linear',
                    queue: false
                }
        });
    });
```